# How to create a registration form Portlet in WebSphere Portel V7?

Tags: websphere-portal

I am using websphere portal version 7. I needs to add an registration form page to portal site and
to implement registration functionality. I didn't find any OOTB portlet to add registration page. 
In which way should I implement this OR Is there any OOTB portlet that I had just missed.

With Regards,
Pranav Kumar

Answer (score 0):

There are some other ways which i think could help you achieve this.

1. You can try creating a Jsp/Html file. And refer it in the information porlet.
2. Create a portlet application in either RAD or WEF (or even eclipse) and install the portlet.